# Debugging in mixed-mode (C++, C#, VB)

Tags: c#, c++, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2019

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode?view=vs-2019) discusses enabling mixed-mode debugging. This allows a managed application to call into a native DLL, or a native application to call into a managed DLL.

Are there negative consequences to enabling this for all projects in my solution? For example, does this negatively impact performance, or build time, or the number of files hitting disk during build, and so on?

The above-mentioned article does not discuss this.

Comment: When debugging, often do not get same performance when code runs without debugging.  You only have issues when you try to run the code without debugging and it doesn't work.  Then you have to figure out why debugging didn't find the errors.

Comment: Well _managed mode_ negatively impacts performance by design so to say, but I'm sure you knew that.

Answer (score 1):

**BuildTime:**

Independent of mixed mode aspects, building time concerns for common Debug configurations are generally reasonable for cases where your native dll/portions' PDBs become very huge (but in general relatively irrelevant in comparison to common release configurations). In doubt, this depends on many aspects (linker configuration, hardware, parallel linking?). With focus on mixed mode, there shouldn't be any further relevant impact reasons since managed parts provide the PDB corresponding information anyways.

**Runtime:**

Depends on many aspects. But yes, in general you will observe an (negative) impact here in comparison to pure native debugging at least, with focus on performance and memory usage(!). For instance, at least former MS-Debuggers (before VS 2017) had several quite serious issues in handling larger debugging sessions in mixed mode. A common - for beginners sometimes not easy to see - performance dropper here are conditional breakpoints on managed and native parts likewise - forcing the debugger to switch its operating context very frequently (conditional break points have almost the same performance impact as "classical" breakpoints).